# terraform init -reconfigure a http backend with no response for running in automation

Tags: terraform

I want to run `terraform init` and reconfigure an `http` backend with a `state file` in the directory and run it in automation pipelines. The problem is when I run it with the `reconfigure` option, it prompts me to answer `yes` or `no`. I want to answer no, but I try to use it in a pipeline. I tried to use `input=false` to suppress the input, but it failed.

How could I initialize a remote `http` backend with a state file in the directory, without using the local (reconfigure) in a pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to programmatically answer 'yes':

```bash
echo yes | terraform init -reconfigure
```